# Fast method to access random image pixels and at most once

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, random

I'm learning OpenCV (C++) and as a simple practice, I designed a simple effect which makes some of image pixels black or white. I want each pixel to be edited at most once; so I added address of all pixels to a vector. But it made my code very slow; specially for large images or high amounts of effect. Here is my code:

```cpp
void effect1(Mat& img, float amount)    // 100 ≥ amount ≥ 0
{
    vector<uchar*> addresses;
    int channels = img.channels();
    uchar* lastAddress = img.ptr<uchar>(0) + img.total() * channels;
    for (uchar* i = img.ptr<uchar>(0); i < lastAddress; i += channels) addresses.push_back(i);   //Fast Enough
    size_t count = img.total() * amount / 100 / 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        size_t addressIndex = xor128() % addresses.size();   //Fast Enough, xor128() is a fast random number generator
        for (size_t j = 0; j < channels; j++)
        {
            *(addresses[addressIndex] + j) = 255;
        }   //Fast Enough
        addresses.erase(addresses.begin() + addressIndex);    // MAKES CODE EXTREMELY SLOW
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        size_t addressIndex = xor128() % addresses.size();   //Fast Enough, xor128() is a fast random number generator
        for (size_t j = 0; j < channels; j++)
        {
            *(addresses[addressIndex] + j) = 0;
        }   //Fast Enough
        addresses.erase(addresses.begin() + addressIndex);    // MAKES CODE EXTREMELY SLOW
    }
}
```

I think rearranging vector items after erasing an item is what makes my code slow (if I remove addresses.erase, code will run fast).

Is there any **fast** method to select each random item from a collection (or a number range) at most once?

Also: I'm pretty sure such effect already exists. Does anyone know the name of it?

Comment: Do you want to select a two random combinations of pixels from an image that have no members in common, set one set to white, and the other set to black?

Comment: @JohnFilleau First, code loops for a specified times (`count`). In each loop, code selects a random available (not selected before) pixel, makes it white (set all channels to 255) and removes it from available pixels. Then, code does these steps again but makes selected pixels black (set all channels to 0). But this method is **extremely slow**. You can run and test my code.

Comment: I'm trying to get a high-level understanding of it first, since there may be a different approach that achieves this even faster.

Comment: @JohnFilleau What I totally need is to select each pixel **"just once"**.

Comment: **"at most once"** because if set amount to a number less than 50, then you'll have some pixels that are totally unaffected right?

Comment: @JohnFilleau You are right. If you set `amount` to a number less than **100**, there are some unaffected pixels. Sorry! I will correct question title.

Comment: enumerate all pixel locations (from 0 to rows*cols-1) in a vector (see std::iota). random suffle it. Make white the pixels corresponding to the first N entries, and to black the next N

Comment: My first naive approach would be to generate a vector of pixel indices: `{0, 1, ..., size - 1}` (make sure you call `std::vector::reserve` before hand), shuffle it, set the pixels corresponding to the first `count` indices black, set the pixels corresponding to indices `[count, min(2*count, img.size()))` to white.

Comment: @Miki beat me to it :)

Comment: Please post answers as "Answer" so I am able to mark them as solution.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I don't have time to post a decent answer. Please go for it ;)

Comment: Before I can post an answer can you tell me about that `xor128` function? Is that from a library? We need a random bit generator for `random_shuffle` to work.

Comment: @JohnFilleau No. It is a simple method. Look at [here](https://codingforspeed.com/using-faster-psudo-random-generator-xorshift/). I need speed and enough randomness. rand() wasn't random enough! :)

Comment: Okay I'll post an answer using C++ <random> library, and then find out how to incorporate your `xor128` function. Must be possible, we'll see how.

Comment: @JohnFilleau That method isn't important. I used it as a fast random generator. Any other good and fast random generator is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes you have a random bit generator function, since `std::random_shuffle` requires that. I don't know how `xor128` works, so I'll use the functionality of the `<random>` library.

If we have a population of `N` items, and we want to select groups of size `j` and `k` randomly from that population with no overlap, we can write down the index of each item on a card, shuffle the deck, draw `j` cards, and then draw `k` cards. Everything left over is discarded. We can achieve this with the `<random>` library. Answer pending on how to incorporate a custom PRNG like you implemented with `xor128`.

This assumes that `random_device` won't work on your system (many compilers implement it in a way that it will always return the same sequence) so we seed the random generator with current time like the good old fashioned `srand` our mother used to make.

Untested since I don't know how to use OpenCV. Anyone with a lick of experience with that please edit as appropriate.

```
#include <ctime>     // for std::time
#include <numeric>   // for std::iota
#include <random>
#include <vector>

void effect1(Mat& img, float amount, std::mt19937 g)    // 0.0 ≥ amount ≥ 1.00
{
    std::vector<cv::Size> ind(img.total());
    std::iota(ind.begin(), ind.end(), 0);   // fills with 0, 1, 2, ...
    std::random_shuffle(ind.begin(), ind.end(), g);
    cv::Size count = img.total() * amount;

    auto white = get_white<Mat>();  // template function to return this matrix' concept of white
                                    // could easily replace with cv::Vec3d(255,255,255) 
                                    // if all your matrices are 3 channel?
    auto black = get_black<Mat>();  // same but... opposite

    auto end = ind.begin() + count;
    for (auto it = ind.begin(), it != end; ++it)
    {
        img.at(*it) = white;
    }
    end = (ind.begin() + 2 * count) > ind.end() ?
               ind.end() : 
               ind.begin() + 2 * count;
    for (auto it = ind.begin() + count; it != end; ++it)
    {
        img.at(*it) = black;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 g(std::time(nullptr)); // you normally see this seeded with random_device
                                        // but that's broken on some implementations
                                        // adjust as necessary for your needs
    cv::Mat mat = ... // make your cv objects

    effect1(mat, 0.1, g);

    // display it here

}
```

## Another approach

Instead of shuffling indices and drawing cards from a deck, assume each pixel has a random probability of switching to white, switching to black, or staying the same. If your amount is 0.4, then select a random number between 0.0 and 1.0, any result between 0.0 and 0.4 flips the pixel black, and betwen 0.4 and 0.8 flips it white, otherwise it stays the same.

General algorithm:

```
given probability of flipping -> f
for each pixel in image -> p:
    get next random float([0.0, 1.0)) -> r
    if r < f
        then p <- BLACK
    else if r < 2*f
        then p <- WHITE
```

You won't get the same number of white/black pixels each time, but that's randomness! We're generating a random number for each pixel anyway for the shuffling algorithm. This has the same complexity unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

> Also: I'm pretty sure such effect already exists. Does anyone know the name of it?

The effect you're describing is called **salt and pepper noise**. There is no direct implementation in OpenCV that I know of though.

> I think rearranging vector items after erasing an item is what makes
>   my code slow (if I remove addresses.erase, code will run fast).

Im not sure why you add your pixels to a vector in your code, it would make much more sense and also be much more performant to directly work on the `Mat` object and change the pixel value directly. You could use OpenCVs inbuild [`Mat.at()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) function to directly change the pixel values to either 0 or 255.

I would create a single loop which generates random indexes in the range of your image dimension and manipulate the image pixels directly. That way you are in O(n) for your noise addition. You could also just search for "OpenCV" and "salt and pepper noise", I am sure there already are a lot of really performant implementations.

Comment: Thanks for effect name. But about main question: 1- I have heard that `Mat.at()` is slower than direct address accessing method. 2- Your solution doesn't meet "each pixel at most once" requirement.

Comment: It is probably still a lot faster than what you are doing right now, you should give it a try. Adding that kind of noise should be very fast, even for big images. The chance that the same pixel is handled twice is very small, especially for big pictures. I'd recommend you to ignore those cases for the sake of perfermance, you will not notice the difference in noise  for the small chance where this happens for a pixel.

Comment: Btw - where have you read about the performance issues for `Mat.at()`? This is new to me, do you remember the reference?

Comment: Actually, "The chance that the same pixel is handled twice" isn't very small when `amount` is near 100. Shuffling vector is good idea and it is working fast even on big images. About "performance issues for `Mat.at()`", I downloaded some video tutorials from a Persian website (I'm Iranian). In that video, the teacher said it while talking about pixel accessing methods.

Comment: You are right - bad wording on my side. What I meant to convey is that it is neglectable for big pictures. You won't be able to find a visual difference even if you flip some pixels twice. The odds that you could flip a substential amount of random pixels twice is low.

Answer (score 0):

I also post a simpler code:

```cpp
void saltAndPepper(Mat& img, float amount)
{
    vector<size_t> pixels(img.total());    // size_t = unsigned long long
    uchar channels = img.channels();
    iota(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), 0);    // Fill vector with 0, 1, 2, ...
    shuffle(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), mt19937(time(nullptr)));    // Shuffle the vector
    size_t count = img.total() * amount / 100 / 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < channels; j++)    // Set all pixel channels (e.g. Grayscale with 1 channel or BGR with 3 channels) to 255
        {
            *(img.ptr<uchar>(0) + (pixels[i] * channels) + j) = 255;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = count; i < count*2; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < channels; j++)    // Set all pixel channels (e.g. Grayscale with 1 channel or BGR with 3 channels) to 0
        {
            *(img.ptr<uchar>(0) + (pixels[i] * channels) + j) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```